# Angular2 Wait for HttpPost response

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post, observable

I have an angular2 app in typescript. I am making a HTTP Post request in order to create a record. This post request happens fine and the record is saved, however, i return the new record from the service and i want to add it to a list in my component and update the DOM with the newly created record. However, it never seems to return in time, is there an accepted way to halt processing until it returns or detect changes in my array and then update the DOM?

My service method is as follows:

```
public AddComment = (comment: RepackComment): Observable<RepackComment> => {
    var json = JSON.stringify({ comment : comment.Comment, rr_id : comment.RepackId, comment_by : comment.CommentBy });
    return this.http.post(this.commentUrl + 'Add', json, {headers: this.headers})
                    .map((response: Response) => <RepackComment>response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And this is my component method:

```
saveComment(): void{
    console.log(this.newComment);
    this.repackService.AddComment(this.newComment)
                    .subscribe((data: RepackComment) => this.addedComment = data,
                    error => console.log(error),
                    () => console.log('Finished creating new comment'));

    console.log("added Comment: " + this.addedComment);
    this.comments.push(this.addedComment);
    this.addNewComment = false;
}
```

So when, `this.addedComment` has been populated with the return value, i want to add it to the `this.comments` array. i then set a flag called `this.addNewComment` which toggles between input and display fields on the front end to display the data.

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT**

As requested here is the appropriate part of my template for these comments. i use PrimeNG for my components:

```html
<p-dataList [value]="comments" [hidden]="addNewComment">
       <header style="height:30px;">
            <button pButton type="button" label="Add Comment" (click)="addComment()" class="actionBtn" style="float:left;width:150px;"></button>
            <span style="margin-left:-105px;font-size:20px;">Comments</span>
       </header>
       <template let-comment>
            <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;" >
                 <div class="ui-grid-row">
                      <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                           <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid comment">
                                <div class="ui-grid-row row-div">
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelFor">ID: </div>
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-7 displayFor">{{comment.ID}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-row row-div">
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelFor">Comment: </div>
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-7 displayFor">{{comment.Comment}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-grid-row row-div">
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelFor">Author: </div>
                                   <div class="ui-grid-col-7 displayFor">{{comment.CommentBy}}</div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </template>
           </p-dataList>
/*INPUT COMPONENTS*/
           <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;" [hidden]="!addNewComment">
                        <div class="ui-grid-row">
                            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                                <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid comment">
                                    <div class="ui-grid-row row-div">
                                        <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelFor">Comment: </div>
                                        <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="newComment.Comment" class="displayFor"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ui-grid-row row-div">
                                        <div class="ui-grid-col-3 labelFor">Author: </div>
                                        <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="newComment.CommentBy" class="displayFor"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="div-row" style="margin-left:40%;">
                            <button pButton type="button" label="Cancel" (click)="cancelComment()" class="actionBtn" style="width:150px;"></button>
                            <button pButton type="button" label="Save" (click)="saveComment()" class="actionBtn" style="width:150px;"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you noticed: `Observables` work async - so everything after your `.subscribe` call probably gets called before the code inside the `.subscribe` callback.

To fix that, you need to put the code, that depends on the results of the `subscribe` call into its callback:

```
saveComment(): void{
    console.log(this.newComment);
    this.repackService.AddComment(this.newComment)
                    .subscribe((data: RepackComment) => {
                        this.addedComment = data;

                        // add your code here
                        console.log("added Comment: " + this.addedComment);
                        this.comments.push(this.addedComment);
                        this.addNewComment = false;
                    },
                    error => console.log(error),
                    () => console.log('Finished creating new comment'));
}
```

Also the object you get back from your post call doesn't match your template. I'd propose this change in your `AddComment` call with `RepackComment` having such a constructor:

```
public AddComment = (comment: RepackComment): Observable<RepackComment> => {
    var json = JSON.stringify({ comment : comment.Comment, rr_id : comment.RepackId, comment_by : comment.CommentBy });
    return this.http.post(this.commentUrl + 'Add', json, {headers: this.headers})
                    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                    .map(res => new RepackComment(res.id, res.comment, res.comment_by))
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: When i execute this, i dont get any errors in the console or anything, however, the DOM refreshes with no object present so it displays with empty values

Comment: But it shows you the message in the console with `"added Comment: { ... }"`? How does your template look like?

Comment: yes i get: `added Comment: [object Object]` so i dont get a json object or anything its just the text `[object Object]`

Comment: i will update the appropriate part of my template into my question now

Comment: Try a `console.log(this.addedComment);`, so it shows the full object and check, if it's empty

Comment: Ok yeah that seems to give me the object as it should be

Comment: Assuming `this.addedComment` is the correct object, you could try slicing the array - maybe `primeNG` doesn't get the changes for some odd reason: `this.comments.push(this.addedComment); this.comments = this.comments.slice();`

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this please? im not too sure what that does

Comment: The `.slice([begin[, end])` method allows you to extract a specific range of an array to a new array. You can however call it without arguments, which copies the whole array into a new one.

Comment: Okay, then the last thing I can think of is calling change detection directly - I will add that to my answer in a second.

Comment: Also looking at the documentation from primeNG here http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatablecrud it looks like it should pick it up by just changing the array

Comment: No luck unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you please show the output of `console.log(this.addedComment);` then? This is really odd :S

Comment: i have added a snippet of the console to my question

Comment: There you go... the object you get back from your `save` call has a different structure than your template expects. `id` vs `ID`, `comment` vs `Comment`, `comment_by` vs `CommentBy`.

Comment: ah crap how did i miss that!!!!!! thanks ill try and map it now and see what i get

Comment: Worked a charm. Simple things. Thanks for all your help and for teaching me so many things in one go :)

Comment: Glad, I could help!! :)